# Exception propagation and std::future

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-studio-2012, future

My understanding is that when an asynchronous operation throws an exception, it will be propagated back to a thread that calls `std::future::get()`.  However, when such a thread calls `std::future::wait()`, the exception is not immediately propagated - it'll be thrown upon a subsequent call to `std::future::get()`.

However, In such a scenario, what is supposed to happen to such an exception if the future object goes out of scope after a call to `std::future::wait()`, but prior to a call to `std::future::get()`?

For those interested, here is a simple example.  In this case, the exception is silently handled by the thread/future package:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

int32_t DoWork( int32_t i )
{
    std::cout << "i ==  " << i << std::endl;
    throw std::runtime_error( "DoWork test exception" );
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto f = std::async( DoWork, 5 );
    try
    {
        //f.get();     // 1 - Exception does propagate.
        f.wait();      // 2 - Exception does NOT propagate.
    }
    catch( std::exception& e )
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I _think_ nothing happens to the exception, it simply gets ignored. (But I'm not familiar enough with this to be certain.)

Comment: I guess its important to note that exceptions are propagated across threads by `std::exception_ptr`s. So to the system the exception looks to be catched and handled until the propagation mechanism decides to rethrow it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is ignored and discarded, just like if you `wait()` for a value but never `get()` it.

`wait()` simply says "block until the future is ready", be that ready with a value or exception. It's up to the caller to actually `get()` the value (or exception). Usually you'll just use `get()`, which waits anyway.

Comment: Gah! I'll buy this, but it is confusing - especially if the std::future created by std::async has a void result type.  Calling get() for such a future feels weird.

Comment: @Bukes: Heh I could see that. But don't think of `future<T>` as "a result of `T`", think of it as "the result of calculating `T`", which of course could be an exception.

Comment: @GManNickG what if function is returning void then don't you think it make sense to call wait() instead of get()

Comment: @GManNickG what if function is returning void then don't you think it make sense to call wait() instead of get()