# Simplest way to make std::thread exception safe

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, exception

`std::thread` class is inherently exception-unsafe since its destructor calls `std::terminate`.

```
std::thread t( function );
// do some work
// (might throw!)
t.join();
```

You could, of course, put everything in between construction and `join()` in a try-catch block, but this can get tedious and error-prone if you know you want to join or detach no matter what happens.

So I was thinking how would one go about writing the simplest possible wrappers around it, but that would also support other hypothetical types of threads. For instance, `boost::thread` or something completely different, as long as it had `joinable()`, `join()` and `detach()` methods. Here's how far I've got:

```
// handles threads safely
// Acts the same as the underlying thread type, except during destruction.
// If joinable, will call join (and block!) during destruction.
// Keep in mind that any exception handling will get delayed because of that;
// it needs to wait for the thread to finish its work first.
template <class UNDERLYING_THREAD = std::thread>
class scoped_thread: public UNDERLYING_THREAD
{
public:
    typedef UNDERLYING_THREAD thread_type;

    using thread_type::thread_type;

    scoped_thread()
            : thread_type() {}

    scoped_thread( scoped_thread && other )
            : thread_type( std::move( other ) ) {}

    scoped_thread & operator = ( scoped_thread && other )
    {
        thread_type & ref = *this;
        ref = std::move( other );
        return *this;
    }

    ~scoped_thread()
    {
        if( thread_type::joinable() )
            thread_type::join();
    }
};

// handles autonomous threads safely
// Acts the same as the underlying thread type, except during destruction.
// If joinable, will call detach during destruction.
// Make sure it doesn't use any scoped resources since the thread can remain
// running after they go out of scope!
template <class UNDERLYING_THREAD = std::thread>
class free_thread
{
    // same except it calls detach();
}
```

This seems to work, but I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid manually defining the constructors and the move assignment operator. Probably the biggest issue I noticed is that compilation will fail if you supply a class with deleted move constructor as a template argument.

Do you have any suggestions about how to possibly avoid this? Or are there other, bigger issues with this approach?

Comment: A `detach()` is a informal way of wasting space in memory and causing hell to pay.

Comment: If you call `detach()` you're basically leaving your program to run amuck without chance of stopping it. It's only used for daemons. Which is what a `detached` thead is called.

Comment: All threads die when a program exits. All, except detached ones. And sincethey don't have `id`s, you'rwnot getting them back. They're anon anod doing whatever you told them to do. One infinite loop from emergency machine shutdown.

Comment: BUT if, you had to detach, and you wanted something to happen when you press a key you would add a mutex to the detached thread and hold std::cin. But as you can see, that'll keep cin stuck to the thread. Therefore it's pointless. Because you couldn't type elsewhere. There is only reasons like listening to ports and such, on servers. Also, machine engineers might use them for a small subset of things.

Comment: @DavidPulse Don't all threads belong to a process that created them and share its virtual memory? Detaching from a thread doesn't change that, does it? It just informs the OS that you're giving up your reference to it and that it can reclaim resources when the thread exits. So when the process terminates, the detached threads terminate as well. Right?

Comment: Well no, not exactly. You give up all rights to that detached thread. It will run until a kill -9 pid or a action from Windows. It's called a daemon when you let it loose like that. Makes it a background process. There's no reason to do it unless you want to make your program a bg process. Which for you would probably not be sensible

Comment: So if I understood this correctly: returning from the main function will not terminate the detached threads, but only the main thread. Terminating the process (e.g. with a kill -9 under *nix, End Process from a Windows task manager or a TerminateProcess Windows API function) will also terminate all detached threads of that process. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, i believe that to be true.

Comment: This thread's characterization of what `.detach()` does is completely wrong. A thread is part of a process. If the process dies all threads are also terminated. `.detach()` gives up the std::thread's ownership  and management of the thread, it can't make it survive process termination!

Answer (score 6):

If you want proper exception handling with asynchronous tasks, maybe you should use `std::future` rather than `std::thread`. Instead of using `join()`, you'd use `get()` on the future, and if the future threw an exception, then `get()` will result in the same exception.

A simple example:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

int my_future_task(int my_arg) {
    throw std::runtime_error("BAD STUFF!");
    return my_arg;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    auto my_future = std::async(my_future_task, 42);
    try {
        my_future.get();
    }
    catch(std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See also:

- [`std::future::get`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/future/get/)
- [`std::future_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future_error)
- [Exception propagation and std::future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222899/exception-propagation-and-stdfuture)

Comment: A trivial example of `std::async` use might help the OP.

Comment: @Yakk - Good point. I got distracted before I really flushed this out—and frankly, I was expecting someone else to post a better answer. Anyway, I've added a simple example.